# Co-countable topology in $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: general-topology

I'm considering $\mathbb{R}$ with the co-countable topology. I'm trying to find all the limit and adherence points of $\mathbb{Z}$

I'm not really sure how to approach the problem. I have already showed that the limit points of $[0,1]$ is all of $\mathbb{R}$

My argument was the following: Lets consider any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and lets suppose that there exist an open set $\mathcal{U}$ such that $x \in \mathcal{U}$ and $\mathcal{U} \cap [0,1]\backslash{x} = \emptyset$, this would imply that $[0,1]\backslash{x} \subset \mathcal{U}^c$ and therefore $[0,1]\backslash{x}$ is countable, which is not true. Therefore, $[0,1]' = \mathbb{R}$.

But I think this argument wouldn't work for $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Since $U=\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$ is co-countable, then $U$ is open. Its complement is closed, but the complement to $U$ is $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thanks, I can see how that implies that $ad(\mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z}$ and I think I can show that $\mathbb{Z}'= \emptyset$

Comment: @AngelPeñaflor . I had made a mistake in the braces, I have edited my answer. It was posted a long while ago. So I lost track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that the derived set of $\mathbb{Z}$ is empty in Co-countable topology take any $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Edit:- I made an error in putting the parantheses, what I wanted to do was consider the irrationals which does not lie in $[n,n+1]$ and also the one's lying in $(n,n+1)$. Which is ofcourse the entire set of irrationals. I have edited and corrected it.

So consider the set $A=(\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q})\cup \{x\}$. Now the complement of this set is $\mathbb{Q}\setminus \{x\}$ which is countable . Hence $A$ is open.

Now $A/\{x\}
\cap\mathbb{Z}=\phi$ . So set $\mathbb{Z}$ has no limit point in co-countable topology. So the set of adherent points of $\mathbb{Z}$ is $\mathbb{Z}$ . As because closure of $\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}\cup\mathbb{Z'}=\mathbb{Z}\cup\phi=\mathbb{Z}$

Edit:- I saw your comment that you can indeed prove it yourself. I did not see it before posting. Regardless , it won't hurt if I leave my answer on.